# iOS: Remove support for old devices

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

The app I'm working on requires a fast device. I've tested it on quite a few (and tweaked the performance as much as I can) but on iPad 1 + 2 it is unusable. Is there any way I can exclude these devices from installing my app? I was just checking the details on them and I can't believe Apple sold the 2 for 3 years and for some reason allowed it to update to iOS 8 (I can't find anyone online that's not complaining about speed since the iOS 8 update on an iPad 2). I know I can use the OS the app is built for to exclude devices but even if I target iOS 8+ the iPad 2 is still supported. Any ideas?

Comment: iPad 2 has the same processor than the iPad mini (currently in markers).

Comment: @OnikIV I know, it also has the same RAM. The performance difference is very noticeable though. Maybe because it's driving a larger screen?  Either way I need to exclude iPad 1 + 2.

Comment: I think the screen is the same 768x1024. Nevertheless, you can use : UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities. More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1

Comment: @OnikIV Thanks for you help. It's strange, I thought they should perform the same but actions that take 3-5 seconds on the Mini 1 take around 10s on the iPad 2. I'll need to investigate further and hopefully I can match the performance eventually but I needed a quick solution and blocking the device is good enough for now.

Comment: I would assume you've tested on multiple iPad 2 devices? Perhaps it's something particular to your test device(s) as opposed to the model itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-info.plist` file for that. If you want to exclude only iPad 2 (and not iPad Mini, iPhone 4S and iPod Touch which have similar hardware) you can require `bluetooth-le` capability (`UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key). The second gen. iPad doesn't have Bluetooth LE so its users won't be able to install your app.

This will also exclude iPhone 4, but as it can't be updated to iOS 8, you are probably going to not support it anyway.

Comment: Thanks for finding a capability that's only missing on the iPad 2, I was just looking through the list. The app is currently iPad only so excluding iPhone 4 isn't an issue.

Comment: Will abusing the 'required device capabilities' in this way risk a rejection?

Comment: You are wright, I think there is a some risk a rejection. Here is the complete list: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH17-SW1

Comment: I can't tell if Apple will reject your app because of that. I require this capability for my app, but it actually uses Core Bluetooth for its core functionality. Required device capabilities are not mentioned anywhere in App Store Review Guidelines.